# Maximal divisor of pairwise differences

Tags: abstract-algebra, combinatorics, elementary-number-theory, polynomials

Let $r \in \mathbb{N}$ be fixed. Define the function:

$$f : \mathbb{Z}^r \to \mathbb{N}, \quad (a_1, ..., a_r) \mapsto \max_{n \in \mathbb{Z}} \prod_{i<j} \gcd((n-a_i), (n-a_j))$$

It is perhaps not immediately clear that the maximum on the RHS exists for every $\textbf{a}$, but by applying the first step of the Euclidean algorithm to each $\gcd$ in the RHS, we see that:

$$f(\textbf{a}) | \prod_{i<j} |a_i - a_j|$$

Let the expression on the right be denoted by $ \sqrt{\Delta} (\textbf{a})$, since it resembles the square-root of the discriminant of the polynomial $p \in \mathbb{Z}[X]$ given by $p(X) = \prod_i (X-a_i)$. It is actually known that $ \sqrt{\Delta} (\textbf{a})$ is a multiple of $0! \cdot 1! \cdots (r-1)!$, and this is attained by some $\textbf{a}$.

**Questions**:

1. What is the minimal value of $f$ subject to the condition that $a_i \neq a_j$ for $i \neq j$?
2. What does the vector $\textbf{a}$ which attains this minimal value "look like"?

These questions have arisen for me while doing some combinatorial number theory. I would actually like the solution for the case with the additional conditions $a_i \in \mathbb{N}$, $(n - a_i) >0$, $n$ even, and disregarding powers of $2$ in $f$(!), but this might overcomplicate the question.